# How do I merge different text files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 txt files:

`file1.txt`:

```
11
```

`file2.txt`:

```
22
```

`file3.txt`:

```
33
```

I want to combine the 3 text files into a single file and put a comma between them.

`endfile.txt` should be as follows:

```
11,22,33
```

I'd try:

```
cat file1.txt; cat file2.txt; cat file3.txt > endfile.txt
```

Wrote line by line but I want to print side by side and put a comma
Could you help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1285136/523458

Comment: Here's one method: `$ cat 1.txt >> out.txt; printf "," >> out.txt; cat 2.txt >> out.txt; printf "," >> out.txt; cat 3.txt >> out.txt;`

Answer (score 1):

`cat file1.txt | cat - file2.txt | cat - file3.txt | tr '\n' ',' | head --bytes -1`

Comment: That could result undesired output in case the files themselves contain multiple new-lines !

Comment: `cat file1.txt | cat - file2.txt | cat - file3.txt` - just `cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`. `cat` is literally named after "ConcATenate files".

Answer (score 0):

A very easy approach simply uses `printf`:

```
(printf "%s" $(cat file1.txt); printf ",%s" $(cat file2.txt file3.txt)) > endfile.txt
```

Which would results in `11,22,33` in `endfile.txt`. The two grouping of `printf` were used to prevent a comma from being written before `11` and the entire line is executed as a subshell so output from all commands is redirected to `endfile.txt`. You may also want to write a final `'\n'` after `file3.txt` to ensure the resulting `endfile.txt` contains a POSIX line-ending.

Comment: @FurkanEryılmaz are your files named `file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt` and are they located in the present working directory where you are running your command? I have run the command many times over and the resulting `endfile.txt` contains `11,22,33`. You will not get any output to the terminal unless you remove the `> endfile.txt` as all output is redirected to that file.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is following.

```sh
$ cat *.txt | sed -z 's/\n\(.\)/,\1/g'
```

If you define exactly order, it is following.

```sh
$ cat file{1,2,3}.txt | sed -z 's/\n\(.\)/,\1/g'
```

---

*CAUTION*

My `sed` is version 4.8.

```sh
$ sed --version | head -n 1
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

Comment: file1= 84G
file2= 15G
file3= 83

when I run your code I get a result like this:
",83G"
unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste`:

```
paste -sd, file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > endfile.txt
```